# How do I scrape the current logged-in Redhat user id in a python script?

Tags: python, linux

I'm creating a script that can be activated by multiple users and act upon files in their home directory.

Currently, I have the code running with a static path, but I really need to set it up to be dynamic. I don't know if it's easier to harvest the current user id or to harvest the current user's home directory... either works for me really, I'm just not sure where to start.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Software Versions:

```
 Python 3.6.1 (default, Jul 10 2017, 18:23:06)
 [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
```

Comment: What you want is easily done with the `os` module. In particular, look at `os.getuid()` and `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give the current username:

```
import os
os.getusername()
```

To get the userid

```
os.getuid()
```

To get the home directory

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
```